# Meaning of >> in print statement

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.x

I was wondering what does `print >> dbfile, key` mean in python.  What is the `>>` supposed to do?

Comment: Incidentally this is considered one of the ickier pieces of Python's syntax. If you prefer `print` to work like every other function, you can put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your code to use the latest behaviour.

Comment: That `__future__` declaration works in 2.6.0a2 and later, mind you. http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be noted that the `>>` syntax is specific to Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, that syntax goes away and code needs to be changed as follows:

```
print >>f, "Hello world"           # Python 2.x

print("Hello world", file=f)       # Python 3.x
```

Comment: I think I like python 3 syntax better because it looks cleaner

Comment: The latter syntax also seems to work if you use `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.7. [`__future__`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) indicates it's available for 2.6.0a2 and up.

Answer (score 9):

This redirects `print` to a file (in this case, `dbfile`).

the `>>` is just a special syntax used for this.

Answer (score 1):

See [“The `print` statement”](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) in the Python language reference. The object indicated must have a `write` method.